# Looking for a translation app I can wear in my ear

Tags: android, translation, bluetooth

I'm looking for a translation app that I can wear in my ear - turn on my bluetooth headset, turn on the app, maybe select a language (I'm specifically after Mandarin), put my phone back in my pocket (although I can get a belt clip if it needs to use the phone's microphone), and have my phone translate anything in the selected language into English in my ear via the bluetooth, without my needing to think about it again for at least a few hours.

There's plenty of translation apps, but they all seem to be "press a button to talk" type programs: I've yet to run across one that'll do what I want.

Any recommendations?  Ideally I'd like one that can work offline (I don't want to constantly rely on an internet connection).

Thank you in advance for the replies.

Edit:
OK, so: Apparently the answer is "Plenty!  But they're all from hardware manufacturers, and are tied to the company's specific, overpriced hardware."

https://smile.amazon.com/Timekettle-M2-Language-Translator-Earbuds/dp/B08GLY854H/
https://smile.amazon.com/ANFIER-Language-Translator-Languages-Translation/dp/B093712JKD
https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B07DKX8KB8/

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.peiko.one&gl=US
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.translation666&gl=US
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wooask.wastrans&gl=US

(Not in order)

Fundamentally, all you really need is parallel processing (one thread to listen for the incoming language and queue snippets for translation, one to translate things out of the translation queue and drop them in the speech queue, and one to read the speech queue aloud), and a way to ensure that the app doesn't end up taking it's own output as input (which a headset of nearly any kind largely solves: speaker is a tiny thing in or by the ear, well away from the microphone).  Most folks will already have basic bluetooth headsets lying around, and if not, you can get them for like $5-15 US if you shop around even slightly.  I'm lost on why nobody seems to have made a separate app for this.  Seems like it's a super obvious thing that'd be insanely useful for basically any international traveler (or anyone who deals with international travelers). Not exactly a small market.